# pdf2image.dll license file missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

1) in my code i am using PDF2Image.dll file to convert pdf to images.in uncompile version it work perfect but when i publish the website and try to convert an image to pdf, it say no license found. 
2) I am using cutewebui ajax uploader to upload files to server. it is the same problem with it. It works fine but when i publish the website then it gives me the same error.
and i do not know where to locate or how to fix the license of file.
so how to locate/fix this?
i am using c#,asp.net

Comment: @Ramhound i am not sure about this license file. suppose if i need it then do i need to download free or to purchase it. i am using version 1.5 for pdf2image.dll

Comment: Have you tried asking whoever provided you with the license file?

Comment: How about researching the problem yourself? I am going to guess PDF2Image is not a free product if it requires a license file. My guess you only need a license file if you are going to have deploy your website.

Comment: @Raymond yes i agree with you,but i cant find out where it is located ? or what extension this file has so i can search it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the deployment procedure, if you already have license file.

[Deployment Procedure From CuteWebUI](http://ajaxuploader.com/document/index.htm#page=LicenseFiledDeployment.htm)

If you don't have a valid license file, then you might have to purchase the license.

Comment: Thanks i have fixed the cutewebui part, i have placed the lic file some where else. Now can you tell me about the pdf license file name or what extension it has so i can find it?

Comment: @safi,  From where did you get "PDF2Image.dll" ? I meant vendor name, website, etc.  The licensing procedure should be similar.

Comment: i download it from a website i do not remember,do you know what is the license extension like cute has .lic then what has pdf2image?

Comment: It will usually ends with .lic extension which is well-known.  but of course some vendor might have their own custom extension. I think you are getting licensing exception mainly due to CuteWebUI, because there is chance that you might be having their evaluation license file.  In order to deploy your application you would need full-licensing.  Contacting CuteWebUI might resolve your issues sooner.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net you can put dlls into to bin directory in webfolder, or you can add them to GAC of server.

for GAC this link might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

but first try to put it bin directory.

Comment: i have put all the dll in asp BIN Folder.

Comment: @Safi - Purchase a license then fellow the directions that Karthik posted.